# Environment inside a longtable with LaTeX

Tags: latex, longtable

I would like to **create a new environment to print a header and a footer between sections of a table**.

I did this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\newenvironment{env}{Heading&&& \\}{\hline \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{7cm}lrr}
    \begin{env}
        Content&b&c&d
    \end{env}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

but I get insulted by the compiler. See [here](http://pastebin.com/UgPzTg5S) for the complete output.

Does someone see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First, you need an \\ at the end of the "`Content&b&c&d`" line.  Second, environments don't work inside tabular/longtable — that's where most of your error messages are coming from.  It may be possible to diddle them into working, but it's way beyond my TeX-fu.  This is the best I can come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\startenv}{Heading\tabularnewline}
\newcommand{\stopenv}{\hline\tabularnewline}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{7cm}lrr}
\startenv
    Content&b&c&d \\
\stopenv
\end{longtable}
```

(It is not strictly necessary to use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\`, but it will avoid headaches if you ever mix this with other environments that use `\\` for their own purposes.)